# Can someone explain the & Operator in these examples?

Tags: c#, operators, bitwise-operators

I don't understand what's going on with this code:

```
if ((_value & item.Value) == item.Value)
{
   item.IsSet = true;
}
```

In this particular example that I'm looking at, I'm seeing the following:

if `_value` is 4103 but `item.Value` is 0, it's true.

if `_value` is 4103 but `item.Value` is 1, it's true.

if `_value` is 4103 but `item.Value` is 2, it's true.

if `_value` is 4103 but `item.Value` is 4, it's true.

if `_value` is 4103 but `item.Value` is 8, it's not true.

if `_value` is 4103 but `item.Value` is 16, it's not true.

if `_value` is 4103 but `item.Value` is 256, it's not true.

if `_value` is 4103 but `item.Value` is 512, it's not true.

if `_value` is 4103 but `item.Value` is 1024, it's not true.

if `_value` is 4103 but `item.Value` is 2048 it's not true.

if `_value` is 4103 but `item.Value` is 4096, it's true.

In another example, I'm seeing the following:

if `_value` is 51 but `item.Value` is 0, it's true.

if `_value` is 51 but `item.Value` is 1, it's true.

if `_value` is 51 but `item.Value` is 2, it's true.

if `_value` is 51 but `item.Value` is 4, it's not true.

if `_value` is 51 but `item.Value` is 8, it's not true.

if `_value` is 51 but `item.Value` is 16, it's true.

if `_value` is 51 but `item.Value` is 32, it's true.

Can someone please explain it to me?

Comment: HINT: Rewrite your question with all the numbers written in *binary* instead of *decimal*. The pattern will become very clear.  (Start with the 51 example; it'll go faster.)

Comment: Why is it, @EricLippert, that I always seem to post an answer, then see some comment you added, and think "Shoot, I should have just said *that*"? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rewrite the numbers in binary, and let's skip the zero case:

```
if _value is 00110011 and item.Value is 00000001, it's true.
if _value is 00110011 and item.Value is 00000010, it's true.
if _value is 00110011 and item.Value is 00000100, it's false.
if _value is 00110011 and item.Value is 00001000, it's false.
if _value is 00110011 and item.Value is 00010000, it's true.
if _value is 00110011 and item.Value is 00100000, it's true.
if _value is 00110011 and item.Value is 01000000, it's false.
if _value is 00110011 and item.Value is 10000000, it's false.
```

You see the pattern? The trues are where the corresponding bit is 1 and the falses are where it is 0.

Answer (score 4):

Bitwise AND, so from your examples:

```
(_value & item.Value) == item.Value

_value = 4103 = 1000000000111 binary
_item.Value = 0  = 0 binary

  1000000000111
& 0000000000000
---------------
  0000000000000

_value = 4103 = 1000000000111 binary
_item.Value = 4096  = 1000000000000 binary

  1000000000111
& 1000000000000
---------------
  1000000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

From **[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**;

The `&` operator can function as either a *unary* or a *binary* operator.

For `integral` types, `&` computes the `bitwise AND` of its operands.

For `bool` operands, `&` computes the `logical AND` of its operands; that is, the result is `true` if and only if both its operands are `true`.

So, when you write `4103`, its actually equal as a binary `1000000000111`. You can find *binary* representation of an integer value like this;

```
int i = 4103;
Console.WriteLine (Convert.ToString(i, 2)); // 1000000000111
```

Process of the rest of that situation is simple calculation with [truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table).

```
  INPUT         OUTPUT
 A   B          A ∧ B
 T   T          T
 T   F          F
 F   T          F
 F   F          F
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a bitwise AND operator. Essentially when you do bitwise AND of integers X and Y and then  compare the result with Y you make sure that X has all bit that are set to 1 in Y also set to 1. X may also have some other bits set to 1, but those we don't care about. Here is MSDN article on the operator:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c(v=vs.71).aspx